# Unable to dockerize Angular app - sh: ng-openapi-gen: not found

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize an Angular app using Docker and Docker compose.

Dockerfile looks like this

```
FROM node:13.10.1-alpine AS build

RUN mkdir /app
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache git

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY ./src ./src
COPY *.json ./
COPY *.js ./
COPY .git ./.git

RUN npm run build
FROM nginx:1.19.4-alpine AS dp-fe_nginx
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY docker/nginx-default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
ENTRYPOINT nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

Docker-compose.yml looks like this

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  dp-fe:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    networks:
      - dp-fe_network
    volumes:
      - dp-fe_volume

volumes:
  dp-fe_volume:

networks:
  dp-fe_network:
    driver: bridge
```

The tasks in package.json looks like this

```
  "scripts": {
    "ng-openapi-gen": "ng-openapi-gen",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run ng-openapi-gen && npm run ng --serve",
    "build": "npm run ng-openapi-gen && npm run ng --build -prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

Where ng-openapi-gen is a feature that allows me to connect to swagger documentation and generate http layer corresponding to that open api swagger doc.

When I run the `run` or `build` task outside a docker, it finish successfuly (app is up and running or there is a dist folder with compiled app).

But when I try to run `docker-compose up`, I am getting this error

```
 > [build 11/11] RUN npm run build:
#17 0.516
#17 0.516 > dp@0.0.0 build /usr/src/app
#17 0.516 > npm run ng-openapi-gen && npm run ng --build -prod
#17 0.516
#17 0.759
#17 0.759 > dp@0.0.0 ng-openapi-gen /usr/src/app
#17 0.759 > ng-openapi-gen
#17 0.759
#17 0.763 sh: ng-openapi-gen: not found
another frames telling me build failed omitted
```

The goal is to build the Angular app (using build task, so first of all I need to run that api generation task and then build whole app), put it into nginx server and expose it on port 4200. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have the tool listed in your `package.json` (probably under `devDependencies`)?

Comment: @DavidMaze yes, that was the problem, dependency was installed globally. Thank you for your help. Can you please post this as an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Docker image is built in a clean environment.  It has no access to the Node installed on the host or any packages you've globally installed there.

If you need a tool like this, you need to make sure it's included in your `package.json` file, probably in the `devDependencies` section.  For example:

```
npm install --save-dev ng-openapi-gen
docker-compose up -d --build
```

If you reference the command through `package.json` `scripts`, `npm run` knows to look for the binary inside the `node_modules` directory.  This setup makes it clear in the package source what exactly is required, and is better practice than needing to know to `npm install -g` an extra package before it can build.

(Your `docker-compose.yml` has unnecessary `volumes:`, and you can just delete them.  Many Node-based setups put their `node_modules` tree in a volume, and if you do this, the old content of the volume will always take precedence over the changed content in the image, meaning changes in the `package.json` will be ignored.  Deleting the `volumes:` here will cause the code and modules in the image to be used.)